# How do I convert a large JSON object to a string looking like console.log() in Node.js

Tags: node.js, json, console.log, stringify

I am trying to stringing a large JSON object without displaying all the children. For example my object has about 20 layers of objects in some places.

At first I was using `console.log(jsonObject)` which output my object perfectly. It would show about 3 layers then if there was an object lower it would display `[object Object]`.

I am trying to get this same effect without logging the result to the console but instead to a string.

I searched for anyone trying to do this, and there's a chance I just didn't know the correct search terms but I found nothing. I also looked for libraries that might handle this with no luck. I was thinking I could rewrite the `JSON.stringify()` but it seemed like there should be an easier way.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish that by using the `inspect` method of the `util` standard library ([util documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options)). That's actually what `console.log` uses internally, with the option `depth` set to `2`.

```
const util = require('util');

const json_object = {
   "name": "StackOverflow",
   "properties":{
      "url":"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67029935",
      "users":{
         "name":"Matt Vine",
         "stats":{
            "reputation": 51,
            "badges": 11
         }
      }
   }
};    

let string = util.inspect(json_object, {depth: 2})
```

This will produce the following string:

```
{ name: 'StackOverflow',
  properties:
   { url: 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67029935',
     users: { name: 'Matt Vine', stats: [Object] } } }
```

---

If you want to keep the "visual" structure of the object you can set the `compact` option to `false`.

```
let string = util.inspect(json_object, {depth: 2, compact: false})
```

Gives us:

```
{
  name: 'StackOverflow',
  properties: {
    url: 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67029935',
    users: {
      name: 'Matt Vine',
      stats: [Object]
    }
  }
}
```